# why does Xcode remove a digit from coordinates?

Tags: xcode, swift, core-location

I am sure there's an easy explanation for this but if I output a coordinate from Google Earth, for example `latitude 50.67454277694554`, using:

```
CLLocation2dCoordinate()
```

to create a coordinate in swift, the terminal output is:

```
latitude: 50.6745427769455
```

It's missing the 4 from the end and the point that plots on the map is about 100m from where there Google Earth one was.

Is there some other additional coordinate variable I can set to get the accuracy back?

Comment: You've got an error somewhere in your app, because I tried in a Playground and after initializing a CLLocation2dCoordinate with 50.67454277694554, its latitude is 50.67454277694554 as expected. Can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: well it get weirder then as i just tried it in playground and it knocks off the last digit there too for me.

Comment: I tried with Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7.3b and it works ok in both cases. Show us a screenshot with your issue, maybe we can detect something.